# Creating sub documents in NodeJS models with multiple JS files

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In a NodeJS project, I've 2 models "News" & "Comments" as below.

```
/* File: Comment.js */
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/* Create Comment Schema */
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the comment text'},
  newsId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "News", required: 'Provide the news ID to which this comment belongs' },
  created_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

```
/* File: News.js */
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/* Create News Schema */
var newsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  link: { type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}, required: 'Kindly enter the link of the news' },
  description: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the description of the news' },
  comments: { type: [commentSchema] }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('News', newsSchema);
```

News model is having array of comments which is a sub document. But it's throwing error

> ReferenceError: commentSchema is not defined.

I noticed that if both the schemas as in one file, it's not throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't importing `commentSchema` in news.js, which is why it works when they are both in a single file.

Comment: Can you pleas help me how to import?

Comment: Import just like you did mongoose: const mongoose = require("mongoose");